# Xamarin.Forms C#: How to put a value on Slider when the page is loaded

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, mvvm, slider

I have some pages in my application.
From the "MainMenu Page" I can navigate to a "Configuration Page".
At the first time,in "MainMenu" I start the parameter "QuestionsToAsk" with 7.

When I call the "Configuration Page" I gave the parameter to the page, and I checked that the correct value is there.
But the Slider shows "1" as the value when the page is loaded.

I use VM to control all the code of the page.

On the XAML I have this code:

```xml
<Label
    Text="{Binding QuestionsToAsk, StringFormat='Questions: {0:F0}'}"/>

<Slider
    Value="{Binding QuestionsToAsk, Mode=TwoWay}"
    x:Name="Slider"
    Maximum="{Binding Maximum}"/>
```

On the VM I have this code:

```
public class VMConfigurationPage : BaseViewModel
{
    int maximum;
    int questionsToAsk;  
  
    public VMConfigurationPage(INavigation navigation, int questionsToAsk)  
    {  
        Navigation = navigation;  
  
        Maximum = 40;  
        QuestionsToAsk = questionsToAsk;  
    }  
  
    public int Maximum  
    {  
        get { return maximum; }  
        set { SetValue(ref maximum, value); }  
    }  
    public int QuestionsToAsk  
    {  
        get { return questionsToAsk; }  
        set { SetValue(ref questionsToAsk, value); }  
    }  
}
```

On the class "BaseModel" I have this code:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged  
{  
    public INavigation Navigation;  
  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
    public void OnpropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string nombre = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nombre));  
    }  
  
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
    }  
  
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)  
    {  
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))  
        {  
            return false;  
        }  
  
        field = value;  
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);  
   
        return true;  
    }  
  
    private string _title;  
    public string Title  
    {  
        get { return _title; }  
        set  
        {  
            SetProperty(ref _title, value);  
        }  
    }  
  
    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingFieled, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)  
    {  
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingFieled, value))  
        {  
            return;  
        }  
  
        backingFieled = value;  
  
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);  
    }  
}
```

When I call the page, I gave a value (for example 7) to the parameter "questionsToAsk".
And I want to have the Slider with the value "7".
But the slider appears in the page with "1", not with the value that I gave to the page.

However, when I modify the Slider, the text shows the correct value. And the parameter "QuestionsToAsk" stores correctly the value of the Slider.

I tried changing the Mode in the Slider with:
`Value="{Binding QuestionsToAsk, Mode=OneWay}"`
And the Label shows "7", but the Slider has 1 as the value.

My problem is to start the value of the Slider at the beginning.

**Any idea about where is the error?**

I tried to change the "Mode".
I tried to use different parameters for the text and for the Slider.
But no results

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the code properly.  As is it is impossible to read

Comment: also, note that the [Slider Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.slider.value?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-slider-value) is a `double`, not an `int`

Comment: @jason I tried with int and double and it's the same, when I "open" the page, my Slider is always with "1".

![Page init...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19JZFo00Yxi8t5tya0QwA00EnbbKAsC1y/view?usp=drive_link)

Here I add 2 images to see my "problem".

![Page values...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ywfrJCYd1Wr5v5_jw6wU25fHwKEwDQb9/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: How are you setting the DataContext on your page?

Comment: @Cheesebaron, I have this in the constructor of the page, after "InitializeComponent" : BindingContext = new VMConfigurationPage(Navigation, questionsToAsk);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the initialization order of the properties of the Slider.

You need to set the `Maximum` before setting the `Value`, because the `Value` gets evaluated *(and potentially capped)* as soon as it was set. `Maximum` has a default value of *1.0*, which is why the `Value` you set gets capped to *1.0*, if you set the `Value` before setting the `Maximum`. `Minimum` has a default value of *0.0*.

This doesn't work, because the properties are always applied in the order they are written in XAML:

```xml
<Slider
    Value="{Binding QuestionsToAsk, Mode=TwoWay}"
    x:Name="Slider"
    Maximum="{Binding Maximum}" />
```

To fix that, just change the initialization order:

```xml
<Slider
    x:Name="Slider"
    Maximum="{Binding Maximum}"
    Value="{Binding QuestionsToAsk}" />
```

Generally, you should always set the properties of the Slider control in this order: `Minimum`, `Maximum`, `Value`. The control will even throw an exception, if you set the `Minimum` value to something that is smaller than the previously set `Maximum`.

Essentially you need to ensure the following at all times:

*Minimum <= Value <= Maximum* where *Minimum < Maximum*

You can find more information about the [Slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/slider) in the official documentation.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!!!
It's incredible that I didn't see this mistake.
Now it's starting with the value of the parameter.
thanks @Julian